# F4 shortcut in myeclipse and its equals in IntelliJ idea

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, myeclipse

In `MyEclipse`, `F4` shortcut use for finding classes that extends/implements/override current type such as `Class/Interface/method`.
This shortcut useful for me.
In `IntelliJ` idea above facility achieve by left green icon of class/interface/method. It means I must click on icon and see list.

My question is : Is there any shortcut in `IntelliJ` idea similar to `MyEclipse` that without mouse I find sub class or method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I think Ctrl-H is what you are looking for.](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/building-class-hierarchy.html)

It will open the inheritance hierarchy in a window.

As [yole](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28912672/66686) mentioned, [if you want to navigate directly to an implementation of a class or method use Ctrl-Alt-B](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp10.5/navigating-to-implemented-overridden-or-implementing-overriding-methods.html). It will open the implementation if there is exactly one, or lets you choose one if there are multiple options.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate | Implementations (Ctrl-Alt-B in the default keymap).